# splitting unsorted list based on increasing and decreasing values in it

Tags: java

I have an unsorted list with float values. I'm able to create graph from that. 
But now, I want to create batches based on up and downs in that graph.

For example, I've an list like below
[6.17, 6.13, 6.12, 6.19, 6.2, 6.21, 6.28, 6.17, 6.2, 6.28]

First batch will be decreasing from 6.17 to 6.12 (index 0 to index 2).

Then second batch will be increasing from 6.12 to 6.28(index 3 to index 6)

All I can think of is to create two methods
increasing(List values) - to get all incremental values
decreasing(List values) - to get all decremental values

Call decreasing() method in increasing() method whenever I find sudden drop in values with sublist from last accessed element and vice-versa

But I don't think this is good idea.

[Please find the graph image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Mki.jpg)

I've an object TimeAnalysis which contains start and end  values. 
In first case start=6.17 and end=6.12.
In second case start=6.12 and end=6.28

I want to get list of TimeAnalysis objects.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I've updated the question. Please check

Comment: Have two lists of lists - incBatches and decBatches. Iterate through the main list comparing each element with the next and keep adding to the a temp list. When you find a point of deflection (where the direction changes), then add this temp list to the appropriate list (incBatches or decBatches). Continue this step until you finish the loop

Comment: what is the criteria of splitting the list ?

Comment: Based on up and downs of the values. 
There are two types of batches one is incremental and other is decremental.
If the batch is incremental batch goes as long as the values are incremented and the batch ends when the values started decreasing. 
Same for the decremental batch also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually split them up you can use `Math.signum`.

```
private List<List<Double>> splitAtInflectionPoints(List<Double> data) {
    List<List<Double>> split = new LinkedList<>();
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < data.size() - 1; i++) {
        double leftSlope = Math.signum(data.get(i) - data.get(i - 1));
        double rightSlope = Math.signum(data.get(i + 1) - data.get(i));
        if (leftSlope != rightSlope) {
            split.add(data.subList(start, i + 1));
            start = i;
        }
    }
    if (start < data.size()) {
        split.add(data.subList(start, data.size()));
    }
    return split;
}

private void test() {
    List<Double> data = Arrays.asList(6.17, 6.13, 6.12, 6.19, 6.2, 6.21, 6.28, 6.17, 6.2, 6.28);
    for (List<Double> run : splitAtInflectionPoints(data)) {
        System.out.println(run);
    }
}
```

Prints:

> [6.17, 6.13, 6.12]
>
> [6.12, 6.19, 6.2, 6.21, 6.28]
>
> [6.28, 6.17]
>
> [6.17, 6.2, 6.28]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that stores the list of values and type of Batch.

```
class Batch {
  enum BatchType {
    INCREASING,
    DECREASING
  };
  BatchType batchType;
  List<Float> values;
}
```

Now you can have a method called splitIntoBatches which returns a list of Batch.

```
public List<Batch> splitIntoBatches(List<Float> values) {
  // Traverse through the list once and create list of batches.
}
```

Comment: But I already have an Object which has start and end values. Now I need the logic to create such batches.

Comment: Just keep to variables one pointing to current value and another to previous value and one more point to whether you are currently looking at increasing or decreasing list. Whenver direction changes, you create a new Batch object and push it into list.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through elements in your array and track if it's increasing or decreasing or possibly the same.

I used **TimeAnalysis** class you mentioned and wrote a static method `splitList()`.

It is to split the list of time floats into list of `TimeAnalysis`.

```
public static List<TimeAnalysis> splitList(List<Float> timeList) {
    if(timeList.size() == 0) return new ArrayList<>();
    else if(timeList.size() == 1) {
        List<TimeAnalysis> batches = new ArrayList<>();
        batches.add(new TimeAnalysis(timeList.get(0), timeList.get(0)));
        return batches;
    }
    ArrayList<TimeAnalysis> batches = new ArrayList<>();
    // 0: same, 1: inc, 2: dec
    int type = -1;
    TimeAnalysis lastBatch = new TimeAnalysis(timeList.get(0), timeList.get
    batches.add(lastBatch);
    timeList.remove(0);
    for(float t : timeList) {
        switch(type) {
            case 0: // same
                if(t > lastBatch.end) { // inc
                    lastBatch = new TimeAnalysis(lastBatch.end, t);
                    batches.add(lastBatch);
                    type = 1;
                } else if(t < lastBatch.end) { // dec
                    lastBatch = new TimeAnalysis(lastBatch.end, t);
                    batches.add(lastBatch);
                    type = 2;
                }
                break;
            case 1: // inc
                if(t > lastBatch.end) { // inc
                    lastBatch.end = t;
                } else if(t < lastBatch.end) { // dec
                    lastBatch = new TimeAnalysis(lastBatch.end, t);
                    batches.add(lastBatch);
                    type = 2;
                } else { // same
                    lastBatch = new TimeAnalysis(lastBatch.end, t);
                    batches.add(lastBatch);
                    type = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 2: // dec
                if(t > lastBatch.end) { // inc
                    lastBatch = new TimeAnalysis(lastBatch.end, t);
                    batches.add(lastBatch);
                    type = 1;
                } else if(t < lastBatch.end) {
                    lastBatch.end = t;
                } else {
                    lastBatch = new TimeAnalysis(lastBatch.end, t);
                    batches.add(lastBatch);
                    type = 0;
                }
                break;
            default:
                if(t > lastBatch.end) type = 1;
                else if(t < lastBatch.end) type = 2;
                else type = 0;
                lastBatch.end = t;
                break;
        }
    }
    return batches;
}
```

When I run:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Float> input = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) input.add(in.nextFloat());
List<TimeAnalysis> output = TimeAnalysis.splitList(input);
for(TimeAnalysis batch : output) System.out.println("start: " + batch.start + ", end: " + batch.end);
```

and give your data as input, I get:

```
start: 6.17, end: 6.12
start: 6.12, end: 6.28
start: 6.28, end: 6.17
start: 6.17, end: 6.28
```